# Mongo finders and criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I use MongoDB in my rails application with Mongoid mapper. But I don't understand `finders` and `criteria` of querying. For example in mongoid documentaion in section `Finders` is query `Model.all`, but if I use that(for example `User.all`), console return criteria and not the result:

```
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {},
  options:  {},
  class:    User,
  embedded: false>
```

But if I use finder `Model.first` or `Model.last`, console return specific result. (`User.first` return specific user, with its fields, as `:email`, `:username` and other). Why `Model.all` wrote in documentation as `finders`? And what I need doing if I need get all `Users` or for example `Posts`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can treat the criteria object as array. Finders return a criteria object because criteria is chainable in mongoid. That is, you can do something like:

```
users = User.where(:activated => true)
users = users.where(:created_at.gte => Time.now - 1.week) unless params[:recent].blank?
users = users.where(:gender => params[:gender].downcase) if %w[m f].include?(params[:gender].downcase
```

Anytime you use any methods which are not defined in `Criteria`, mongoid will actually run the query and fetch the results and treat them as array. If you specifically want the results to be returned as array, you can always call `User.all.to_a`. But keep in mind that following two are mostly equivalent:

```
User.all.each {|u| puts u.id}
User.all.to_a.each {|u| puts u.id}
```

But there is one issue with the later, it will fetch all the documents in memory once and can lead to too much of memory consumption. However, first one uses Mongodb cursors to fullest and only loads documents yielded by cursor, means controlled memory usage.

Comment: Absolutely agree! Thank for explanation.