# Mongoid querying inclusion Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am implementing user setting in my rails website where a user has control over who can send him notifications. The allowed classed of users who can send him information is stored in an array and can be set by the user.

How do I query users to send the notification according to the user type of the user who sent the post.

I want to do something like this.

```
notifiable_users = User.all.or("notification_setting.posted_by" includes "sender.user_type")
```

Comment: what is `all.or` supposed to mean?

Comment: I am just adding filters to all users using the or chaining of mongoid.

Comment: but doing this, I guess you load all users first, then you filter objects in memory, why don't you make directly a more precise query to lower the db call?

Comment: @apneadiving most of the criteria methods in mongoid are also model methods, i.e. you can do both `Model.all.where(...)` and `Model.where(...)`, but `or` is not a model method and only works for criteria, so it is necessary to do `Model.all.or(...)`. Now on to filtering objects in memory, that is not the case, mongoid creates query using the criteria objects and evaluates them lazily. So, it doesn't ask DB for results until you use some method on criteria which can not be chained to add to the query. refer to http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html for details.

Comment: @rubish: I only see `any_of` there, not `or`, where is it defined? Also in ActiveRecord, and I fear, it's the same in Mongoid doing `.all` triggers the call directly. `Model.scoped` is then preferred.

Comment: @apneadiving `any_of` and `or` are aliases. They both do the same thing. I can confirm `Model.all` doesn't fire the query, it just returns a criteria.

Comment: @rubish: thanks for aliases, for `.all`, why do you think so, any reference?

Comment: @rubish: in the mongoid doc, `any_of` can be used directly on the model so your previous argument seems wrong.

Comment: @apneadiving I have been using mongoid for a year now, and just confirmed in console before posting the comment :). I do not remember any references though. I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445958/mongo-finders-and-criteria/8446427#8446427

Comment: @apneadiving That's strange, on using `show-method Model.all.or` in pry console it shows the code for `any_of`, running `Model.all.or(...)` and `Model.any_of(...)` generate similar criteria object. Still `Model.or(...)` throws the missing method error. I generally prefer `Criteria#or` because of similarity with mongodb identifier, but using any_of directly on model might be better way of doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `notification_setting.posted_by` is an array for the allowed user types and `sender.user_type` is the user_type(singular, not an array) of sender, you can simply do:

```
notifiable_users = User.all.or("notification_setting.posted_by" => sender.user_type)
```

If it is the other way around:

```
notifiable_users = User.all.or("notification_setting.posted_by".to_sym.in => sender.user_types)
```